# Smallest OCI Container That Handles PID 1 Signals Correctly

Tags: code-golf

## Introduction

There have been a few examples of the smallest possible OCI container that does "X". However these examples never correctly handle termination signals.

## Challenge

Produce the smallest possible container that correctly handles PID 1 signal responsibilities.

The container does not need to manage child processes.

The container does not need to emit anything to stdout.

It merely needs to start and stay "running" until any graceful termination signal arrives and then exit with exit code 0.

If any non graceful termination signal arrives it should respond per convention.

It should not use CPU unnecessarily. I expect solutions that "sleep" would take less code anyway. Extra bonus kudos for figuring out how to not block or occupy any threads.(Probably not possible, but I don't know enough about this area to say for sure.)

You my use any container build system.

## Example Naive Incorrect Solution

```c
//a.c
#include <signal.h>

int main() {
  pause(); //does not handle signals at all, never returns, only dies on SIGKILL
  return 0;
}
```

```
# Dockerfile
FROM alpine AS build
RUN \
  apk update && \
  apk add --no-cache build-base
COPY a.c .
RUN gcc -o a -Wall -s a.c --static
FROM scratch
COPY --from=build a .
CMD ["/a"]
```

## Test Protocol

`start`

```bash
> docker create --name tiny <image:tag>
> docker start tiny
> docker stop tiny
# should exit immediately
> docker inspect tiny --format='{{.State.ExitCode}}'
# should return 0
> docker rm tiny
```

`run`

```bash
> docker run --name tiny
^C # Control-C
# should exit immediately
> docker inspect tiny --format='{{.State.ExitCode}}'
# should return 0
> docker rm tiny
```

`SIGHUP`, `SIGQUIT`, [Job Control Signals](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Signals.html)

```bash
# TBD - I will accept entries that ignore these
# bonus kudos if you provide an alternate that includes appropriate handling of these signals
```

## Winning Condition

- Container correctly reacts to `SIGINT` and `SIGTERM` [Termination Signals](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Termination-Signals.html)
- Smallest size as shown with `docker image inspect --format='{{.Size}}' <image:tag>`
- Source code size is NOT considered
- Build files sizes are NOT considered
- Only resulting image size is scored

References:

- https://idbs-engineering.com/docker/containers/2021/01/28/container-competition.html
- https://jpetazzo.github.io/2020/02/01/quest-minimal-docker-images-part-1/
- https://devopsdirective.com/posts/2021/04/tiny-container-image/
- [https://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html](https://www.muppetlabs.com/%7Ebreadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53382589/smallest-executable-program-x86-64
- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#specify-an-init-process
- https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Signal-Handling.html
- https://github.com/krallin/tini
- https://github.com/Yelp/dumb-init
- https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/distroless/issues/550#issuecomment-791610603
- https://www.google.com/search?q=pid+1+container